# Editing data table in shiny app with incremental calculation

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently working on a shiny app in which I would like for a user to go in and make some changes to a specific column on a displayed table that then triggers a calculation to be done and the table displayed to be updated. For example, taking the following data frame:

```
input_data <- data.frame(ITEM_NO = c("1000001", "1000001","1000001", "20001", '20001', '20001'),
                     AVAILABLE_QTY = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 500,500,500),
                     DEMAND = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     FORECAST = c(0,0,0, 0 ,0, 0),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to be able to change the forecast column in a way that triggers a simple incremental calculation to subtract the entered forecast from the the available qty. The trick is I'd like to be able to have the app do separate calculations for each individual item. I have something coded up that works on an individual item, so if I only do it for 1000001, it would work, or if I only do it for 20001, it works, but when I try to make edits for both at the same time it crashes with this error: "Warning: Error in [.data.table: j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..j]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
". Would anyone be able to help me adjust this code so that it works in that scenario?

Here's the full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
input_data <- data.frame(ITEM_NO = c("1000001", "1000001","1000001", "20001", '20001', '20001'),
                         AVAILABLE_QTY = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 500,500,500),
                         DEMAND = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                         FORECAST = c(0,0,0, 0 ,0, 0),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#=================================================================
modFunction <- function(input, output, session, data,reset) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(data = data)
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy("mod_table")
  
  #need to change this function so that the data gets group split
  observeEvent(input$mod_table_cell_edit, {
    print(names(v$data))
    info = input$mod_table_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    str(info)
    print(i)
    print(j)
    print(k)
    isolate(
      #try putting the list stuff out here instead and see if it gets rid of the e
      if (j %in% match(c("FORECAST"), names(v$data))) {
        print(match(c("FORECAST"), names(v$data)))
        v$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, v$data[i, j])
        print(v$data)
        
        if(j %in% match('FORECAST', names(v$data))){
          #convert to a list
          test_stuff<- v$data
          start_list<- test_stuff %>% group_split(ITEM_NO)
          end_list<- list()
          for(t in 1:length(start_list)){
            start<- start_list[[t]]
            for(n in 2:nrow(start)){
              start$AVAILABLE_QTY[n] <- start$AVAILABLE_QTY[n-1]-start$DEMAND[n]-start$FORECAST[n]
            }
            end_list[[t]]<- start
            
          }
          final<-  data.table::rbindlist(end_list)
          v$data<<- final
            
        }
      } else {
        stop("You cannot change this column.") # check to stop the user from editing only few columns
      }
    )
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
  })
  ### Reset Table
  observeEvent(reset(), {
    v$data <- data # your default data
  })
  
  print(isolate(colnames(v$data)))
  output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(v$data, editable = TRUE)
    
  })
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("mod_table"))
  
}
#===================================================
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
      tags$hr(),
      modFunctionUI("editable")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    demodata<-input_data
    callModule(modFunction,"editable", demodata,
               reset = reactive(input$reset))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because `final` is a data.table and you assign it to `v$data`.  As long as `v$data` is a dataframe, it works fine.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

input_data <- data.frame(ITEM_NO = c("1000001", "1000001","1000001", "20001", '20001', '20001'),
                         AVAILABLE_QTY = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 500,500,500),
                         DEMAND = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                         FORECAST = c(0,0,0, 0 ,0, 0),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#=================================================================
#modFunction <- function(input, output, session, data,reset,globalSession) {
modFunction <- function(id, data, reset) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  observe({v$data <- data()})
  
  output$mod_table <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(v$data, editable = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy("mod_table" ) #, session = globalSession)
  
  #need to change this function so that the data gets group split
  observeEvent(input$mod_table_cell_edit, {
    
    print(names(v$data))
    info = input$mod_table_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col + 1
    k = info$value
    # str(info)
    print(i)
    print(j)
    print(k)
    myvar <- match(c("FORECAST"), names(v$data))
    isolate(
      #try putting the list stuff out here instead and see if it gets rid of the e
      if (j == myvar) {
        print(myvar)
        v$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, v$data[i, j])
        print(v$data)
        
        #if(j %in% match('FORECAST', names(v$data))){
          #convert to a list
          test_stuff<- v$data
          start_list<- test_stuff %>% group_split(ITEM_NO)
          end_list<- list()
          lapply(1:length(start_list), function(t){
          #for(t in 1:length(start_list)){
            start<- start_list[[t]]
            for(n in 2:nrow(start)){
                start$AVAILABLE_QTY[n] <- start$AVAILABLE_QTY[n-1]-start$DEMAND[n]-start$FORECAST[n]
            }
            end_list[[t]]<<- start
            
          #}
          })
          final <-  data.table::rbindlist(end_list)
          v$data<<- as.data.frame(final)
          
          #}
          
      } else {
        stop("You cannot change this column.") # check to stop the user from editing only few columns
      }
    )
    
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
  })
  ### Reset Table
  observeEvent(reset(), {
    v$data <- data() # your default data
  })
  
  print(isolate(colnames(v$data)))

  })
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("mod_table"))
  
}

#===================================================
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
      tags$hr(),
      modFunctionUI("editable")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    demodata <- reactive({input_data})
    modFunction("editable", demodata, reset = reactive(input$reset))
    #callModule(modFunction,"editable", demodata,reset = reactive(input$reset),globalSession = session)
  }
)
```

Comment: Wow I appreciate it! I figured it was going to be something simple and I was going to be hitting myself over the head when it was figured out- and I was right! Thanks again!